# visual studio 2019 open solution file incompatible

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I think I was using visual studio 2017 and wrote a SSIS package. Now I installed visual studio 2019 and can't open the solution file. Error:

> Unsupported This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the
>   following projects. The project types may not be installed or this
>   version of Visual Studio may not support them.  For more information
>   on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets,
>   please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after
>   clicking OK.
>      - ABC, "C:\Users\XYZ\ABC.dtproj"
>
> Non-functional changes required Visual Studio will automatically make
>   non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable
>   them to open in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio
>   2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be
>   impacted.
>      - ABC_SSIS, "C:\Users\XYZ\ABC_SSIS.sln"

I tried "Right-click on the project and reload" - didn't work.

I tried to confirm SSDT is installed:
it is installed at the installation interface, but doesn't exist in extension manager:
[image: installed SSDT]

[image: no SSDT in extension manager]

Comment: I have had similar issues with other type of project. It turned out our endpoint security software prevented installation of some components. Have you ruled that out? For me the projects that worked in VS 2017 stopped loading in 2019 just like what you are seeing.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

SSIS is a seperate extension now in Visual Studio 2019. You can install that extension in Visual Studio market place. Choose Online tab and search for "SQL Server Integration Services Projects".Hope it can help your problem

Comment: Just a note: after installing the extension you may have to right click on your project in VS and click "Reload"

Comment: It isn't working in my case. I tried install and enable it from Extensions but doesn't work.

Answer (score 12):

- 1.Extensions -> Microsoft Reporting Service Project
- 2.and then close visual studio
- 3.VSIX installer will complete automatically
- 4.If your project unloaded, right click on project and reload

Comment: reload was key for me1  VS reported incompatible until reload.

Comment: It isn't working in my case. I tried install and enable it from Extensions but doesn't work.

Comment: Reload did the trick for me when trying to migrate an old SSIS package created in VS 2015 to VS 2019...

Answer (score 5):

Today I faced this issue,

**Cause**

The reason for issue is,
I saw a yellow bg notification at the top of IDE showing performance issue  [image: screenshot included], with option to "disable this" to improve the performance.
I chose disable, later next day when I opened the project, It showed the project is not compatible.
I did Repair SSIS, Uninstall and Reinstall SSIS,  and also updated the SSIS to latest version. None of these 3 ways resolved the issue.

**Solution**

But, I found Manage Extension submenu item under Extension menu,  Under installed tab, SSIS extension was in disabled status. I reverted to Enabled status.  Sample screenshot of the same for reference is here. If it disabled, simply enable it. Then restart VS with SSIS project.
[image]

Comment: This was also a lesson for me that I tell all of my relatives, I didn't read the message and just clicked something. The correct answer is "Don't report this extension again" to avoid having to follow these steps :)

Comment: I just did the same damn thing for SSRS. I clicked disable like an idiot

Comment: @rXc3NtR1c disabling SSIS gave me difficult time!

Comment: It isn't working in my case. I tried install and enable it from Extensions but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Enabling the SSIS in manage extensions solved this for me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Extensions ... Manage Extensions
2. Online ... Visual Studio Marketplace
3. SQL Server Integration Services Projects
4. Download
5. Close Visual Studio and then run the download
6. When finished, open your existing SSIS project and right-click the project and select "Reload" or "Reload with dependancies"

You can also now start a new Integration Services project.

[image: Manage Extensions]