# SSIS and Visual Sudio 2019 Cannot Load Project

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

First of all, this issue has nothing to do with the installation of SSDT. I have the lastest version installed, at the time of writting this.

My issue is that the SSIS package was written some time ago using, I think either VS2005 or VS2008 as I was using Windows 7 with the lastest SSDT package fro the time, and I now need to open it up to view the workings.

I am now using VS2019 on Windows 10, again with the latest SSDT package, and studio refuses to open the project.

```
Unsupported
This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them.
For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.
     - Contessa.SQL.SSIS, "G:\Work Stuff\Solution\40 SQL SSIS\TestSolution.SQL.SSIS\TestSolution.SQL.SSIS\TestSolution.SQL.SSIS.dtproj"


Non-functional changes required
Visual Studio will automatically make non-functional changes to the following projects in order to enable them to open in Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2013, Visual Studio 2012, and Visual Studio 2010 SP1. Project behavior will not be impacted.
     - Contessa, "G:\Work Stuff\Solution\TestSolution.sln"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer and it had nothing to do with the SSDT installed.

After finding this article.

[visual-studio-2019-open-solution-file-incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914342/visual-studio-2019-open-solution-file-incompatible)

It explains the need to make sure that the SSIS Extension is enables. In my case it needed to be installed.

This occurred because I had installed various versions of SSDT which caused Visual Studio to need me to reinstall.